# determine button click of button in html in objective c code

Tags: javascript, html, ios, uiwebview

I have a payment html Page which I load in a webview in an iOS app.
I want to write some code in Objective C when submit button in the form is clicked.
I know we can detect click using navigationtype like this but this does not work:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormSubmitted) {
         NSLog("inside submit");
    }
    return YES;
  }
```

Please let me know if we can do it any other way.

Comment: What happens after submit button is clicked?...does it redirect to another link?...if it does you can compare url it is redirecting to and execute code accordingly.

Comment: Now I edited my answer and please check it.

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to set UIWebViewDelegate Method and I give you sample navigating code.You need to customize here.

```
#pragma mark - UIWebView Delgate Method
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
  switch (navigationType)
  {
    case UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked:
        //When User tapped a link. 
        break;
    case UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther: 
       //Some other action occurred. 
       break;
    case UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormSubmitted:
        //user submitted a form. 
       break;
    case UIWebViewNavigationTypeBackForward: 
       //User tapped the back or forward button. . 
       break;
    case UIWebViewNavigationTypeReload:
       //User tapped the reload button. 
      break;
     case UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormResubmitted
       //User resubmitted a form. . 
      break;
   }
 return YES; 
}
```

[UIWebNavigationTypes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIWebViewNavigationType)

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem I was getting was because the type of submit button I was specifying was different and it was not redirecting correctly.